# Using spell with a bonus action when we had 2 actions (Haste or Action Surge as example)

Tags: dnd-5e, spellcasting

The Players Handbook says:

> A spell cast with a bonus action is especially swift. You must use a bonus action on your turn to cast the spell, provided that you haven't already taken a bonus action this turn. You can't cast another spell during the same turn, except for a cantrip with a casting time of 1 action.

What if we had the power of the spell *Haste* (as example), or Action Surge (fighter feature), where the player has 2 actions + 1 bonus. Then the player use a bonus action for a spell. Must then **both** actions be a *Cantrip*, or only one?

Comment: I added Action Surge as another potential example, since that one is specifically mentioned in our canonical question on this. You’ll find a handy table outlining what uses are legal/illegal in the linked duplicate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Both spells cast as an action must be cantrips

The wording of the rule is unambiguous (emphasis mine):

> A spell cast with a bonus action is especially swift. You must use a bonus action on your turn to cast the spell, provided that you haven't already taken a bonus action this turn. **You can't cast another spell during the same turn, except for a cantrip with a casting time of 1 action**.

If it's still the same turn, you cannot cast any other spell other than a cantrip with the casting time of one action. Thus even though you have two actions, the only spells that may be cast with them are cantrips.

#### Regarding *haste*:

You mention having two actions and a bonus action due to being under the effect of the *haste* spell. You may want to note that the *haste* action is less powerful than a normal action, and cannot be used to cast a spell:

> Choose a willing creature that you can see within range. Until the spell ends, the target's speed is doubled, it gains a +2 bonus to AC, it has advantage on Dexterity saving throws, and it gains an additional action on each of its turns. **That action can be used only to take the Attack (one weapon attack only), Dash, Disengage, Hide, or Use an Object action.**

It is possible to have two regular actions and a bonus action available on a turn, for example through the use of Action Surge, but the above rule still stands.

Comment: I thought that too. Thank you for the confirmation and clarification! By the way: *Haste* was only an example. What was important to me was if the player (for whatever reason - Hombrew, etc.) had 2 actions.